# How do we add UIDatePicker in TableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift3

PartiesTableViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")

        cell.textLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].name

        //----------how do we add UIDatePicker in the cell??----------

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].address

        return cell
}
```

AddPartyViewController:

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    print("save clicked \(nameTextField.text)")

    party.lists.append(list(name: nameTextField.text!, address: addressTextField.text!, startDate: datePicker.date))

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //when button clicked, go back to front page, which is PartiesTableViewe
}
```

Party:

```
import UIKit

var party: Party = Party()

struct list
{
    //var id:String
    var name:String
    var address:String
    var startDate:Date
}
class Party: NSObject
{
    var lists = [list]()

    func addParty(name: String, address: String, startDate: Date)
    {
        //lists.append(list(date:date, name: name, address: address))
        lists.append(list(name: name, address: address, startDate:startDate))
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading! I am very new to Swift 3 and I was working on todo list with UIDakePicker. I was struggling with adding UIDatePicker into tableview cell and I was able to add party name and party address by using "cell.textLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].name" and "cell.detailTextLabel?.text = party.lists[indexPath.row].address".

name appears in cell and address appears right below name in the same cell. I was trying to display date that is selected by UIDatePicker in AddPartyViewController right next to name in tableview cell so all 3 of them are in the same cell.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Add text field in your tableview.Create a datepicker by code and give it to the input view of that textfield.

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datepicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
 [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//In datepickerValueChanged function do the things to update your textfield.
```